# Angular 2: module with conditional dependency on `@angular/forms`

Tags: angular, typescript, module, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

I'm developing a simple Angular 2 reusable component - a captcha form field, using RC5. I don't want the users of this module to have to serve `@angular/forms` if they're not using it (cause the component is self-sufficient).

Let's bring some code in:

```
// Independent of '@angular/forms'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-captcha',
  template: `...`,
})
export class CaptchaComponent {}

// Depends on '@angular/forms'
@Directive({ selector: 'my-captcha' })
export class CaptchaValueAccessorDirective {}
```

Now, I have to export this in some way, preferably in an `NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ CaptchaComponent ],
  exports: [ CaptchaComponent ],
})
export class CaptchaModule {}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ CaptchaValueAccessorDirective ],
  exports: [ CaptchaValueAccessorDirective ],
  imports: [ FormsModule ],
})
export class CaptchaFormsModule {}
```

It's 2 modules - 1 with `@angular/forms` dependency, the other one without it.

Yet my assumption is that mostly this will be used in conjunction with `@angular/forms`, the other case being more of an edge-one.

How can I ensure that:

1. Users not dependent on `@angular/forms` do not have to load it when `CaptchaComponent` is in use (this one is currently achieved)
2. Users that *do depend* on `@angular/forms` have to only include one `NgModule` (instead of both `CaptchaModule` and `CaptchaFormsModule` now)

Comment: Depending on how the things are structured, CaptchaFormsModule may be a parent module for CaptchaModule, or both modules can be child modules for common parent.

Comment: Looks like what I want can be achieved pretty easily with 2 modules: `CaptchaFormsModule` and `CaptchaNoFormsModule`, each of those will provide the `CaptchaComponent`. So users will only have to require one of those, and the other one will be eliminated by tree-shaking

Comment: I personally consider a good thing for public items to be directly available for import, like `captcha-package/lib/captcha-no-forms`. No need to rely on tree-shaking in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking the approach of 2 self-sufficient modules for these 2 usecases:

```
// captcha-package/index.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ CaptchaComponent, CaptchaValueAccessorDirective ],
  exports: [ CaptchaComponent, CaptchaValueAccessorDirective ],
  imports: [ FormsModule ],
}) export class CaptchaFormsModule {}
...
import { CaptchaFormsModule } from 'captcha-package';
```

and

```
// captcha-package/captcha-noforms.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ CaptchaComponent ],
  exports: [ CaptchaComponent ],
}) export class CaptchaNoFormsModule {}
...
import { CaptchaNoFormsModule } from 'captcha-package/captcha-noforms';
```

This results in the desired behavior: 1) each type of users can use the component by importing **a single** package and 2) "no-forms" users do not have the `@angular/forms` overhead.